# СПП местоименно-союзное?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Они знают, что днем у нас начнется выдвижение к реке плавсредств огневых позиций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это союз. К тому же союз здесь можно опустить без ущерба смысла. Ср.: Они знают: днем у нас начнется выдвижение к реке плавсредств огневых позиций.

Comment: Но его всё равно колотило и взбулындывало так, что земля сверху сыпалась. 

А это подходит?

Comment: Нет. Ср.:  Она не сводила глаз с дороги, ***что*** ведёт через рощу (союзное слово что — подлежащие. Дорага какая ?- что ведет. Союзное слово относится к слову дорога. На него падает логическое ударение, его нельзя изьять из предложения.

Comment: Он не верил, что вредителем мог быть зачуханный котельщик Зыков.
???

Comment: Нет. Союзное слово всегда является членом предложения, к нему можно задать вопрос. Ср.: Я спросил, что (союзное слово) мы делали на уроке. Смысл потеряется, если его изъять из предложения.